# Proof of Concept with selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

What are the parameters to do the POC of the application and making sure it's right candidate for Selenium Automation and then how to begin from there?

Comment: This is potentially a really interesting question, but it's so vague. People won't invest their time in solutions if they don't know they're actually relevant or helpful to you.

Comment: @Andrew:  I agree with you there are many things  I know about this.Even I can write a story about this.But I was thinking what would be the best of the best approach that can taken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know your goals, then the issue is to show how Selenium can achieve those goals.

If you don't know your goals, then every tool is the wrong tool until you know what it is you wish to accomplish.

Selenium is good at automating testing of web applications across multiple different web browsers.  Some aspects of that testing are better than others, and all of those tests will be written by the testing team that leverages Selenium to verify the application's correct appearance or functionality.

If you have a web application, but don't know how you might test it (possibly because you don't have a test plan) Selenium won't provide a good test plan.  It will just provide a set of tools that make some test plans much easier to implement.

Answer (score -1):

I think what business problems selenium solves in that application.

Comment: Instead of down voting you can give your solution so that others can judge it.

Comment: You need to elaborate on the statement.